# How to come out from program

Tags: python

Question:
Given a string S, find the largest alphabetic character, whose both uppercase and lowercase appear in S. The uppercase character should be returned. For example, for S = "admeDCAB", return "D". If there is no such character, return "NO".

```
s=input()
l=[0]*26
u=[0]*26
ln=len(s)
for i in range(ln):
    if(s[i].islower()):
        l[int(ord(s[i])-ord(('a')))]=1
    else:
        u[int(ord(s[i])-ord(('A')))]=1
for i in range(25,-1,-1):
    if(l[i]==1 and u[i]==1):
        print(chr(i+ord('A')))
        
print(NO)
```

How TO EXIT once print(chr(i+ord('A'))) gets printed

Comment: What is your code supposed to do in the first place? Either way, it's not C; characters (one-length strings) and integers are not interchangeable.

Comment: `'a'` and `'A'` are the same as `"a"` and `"A"` in Python.  They are both 1-character strings.  If you want their ascii values, use `ord('a')` and `ord('A')`.  To convert integers back to 1-character strings, use `chr(n)`.

Comment: Please explain what you intended to do with this code.

Comment: Given a string S, find the largest alphabetic character, whose both uppercase and lowercase appear in S. The uppercase character should be returned. For example, for S = "admeDCAB", return "D". If there is no such character, return "NO".

Comment: You can better use return statement instead of print() in last but before line

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question,

> Given a string S, find the largest alphabetic character, whose both uppercase and lowercase appear in S. The uppercase character should be returned. For example, for S = "admeDCAB", return "D". If there is no such character, return "NO".

in a Pythonic way,

```
def f(s):
    s = set(s)
    for c in 'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA':
        if c in s and c.lower() in s:
            return c
    return 'NO'
```